# I created a textbook supplement for Electric Circuits. Am I missing anything critical?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, books, review

Please note I have tried my best to follow the rules of posting and this post follows them as far as I know, thank you.

---

**Edit: ** The course covers the following sections:

1. Circuit Variables
2. Circuit Elements
3. Simple Resistive Circuits
4. Techniques of Circuit Analysis
5. The Operational Amplifier
6. Inductance, Capacitance, and Mutual Inductance
7. Response of First-Order RL and RC Circuits
8. Natural and Step Responses of RLC Circuits
9. Sinusoidal Steady-State Analysis

---

Hi, I am a second year Engineering student, and I designed a textbook supplement of sorts in preparation for my Electric Circuits course.

A rough draft can be viewed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w0qj6ywrzcv79n/basic.pdf?dl=0).

The purpose of this is to help myself and my classmates with the course by only having important equations and definitions, and not derivations and other non-directly useful elements.

My question is, does it appear as if I am missing anything critical that is not included? Additionally, is there any mistakes that I made? As I have not myself began the course yet, all my knowledge is purely based off of several textbooks themselves, so errors may have been made unbeknownist to me.

I realize this is unconventional and cannot replace a traditional textbook; I mainly began this project as a way to learn more LaTeX and become familiar with the course.

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: How can we spot what may be missing as we don’t have a course syllabus or scheme of work?

Comment: @SolarMike Apologies; the course outline has been added. Thanks.

Comment: Derivations of some equations tend to be the most useful based on various assumptions - why leave them out...

Comment: The book that I found most useful was Geick - Technical Formulae, had all the formulae, functions that an engineer was likely to need including algebra, solid geometry, trigonometry,calculus etc...

Comment: Over, under and critically damped RLC is not for \$\zeta\$ = 0. If you want *some* help on RLC AC and transient response look [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html) but otherwise I'm voting to close this question as it solicits opinions too much and there is no real definition of aims. In other words it cannot be answered as either yay or nay.

Comment: I want to simultaneously upvote this, and vote to close as opinion based (I settled on just the upvote). But what a great project! And I envy your LaTeX skills.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add *source shifting* to the list of useful stuff. It's not hard to understand, and can help to convert sources to the right type using source transformations.

I also don't understand why RLCM-circuits are discussed under **DC Circuits**. In DC an inductor can be considered a short-circuit, and a capacitor an open circuit. The chapter seems to describe transient or large-signal behavior.

Also, in opamp circuits I *always* force my students to first check for *negative* or *positive* feedback using what I call the "arrow method" - I don't know if it has an original name. **Only** if there is negative feedback, and \$A\to \infty\$, you can say that \$v_p = v_n\$. If the feedback is *positive*, then the opamp should be treated as a comparator, and \$v_p \neq v_n\$.